# how to post photo with text to facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Current, I can upload a photo to an user's album. but I can't use the url of this photo(assemble the url by the photo id), it says:"**FBCDN image is not allowed in stream**", I also figured out that facebook forbid user to do this.

I know that I can upload the photo to somewhere else on the internet, but actually I don't have that 'somewhere', so how does everybody do ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to assemble the url of the picture you just uploaded. Instead, use the photo_id that you got back and make another call to the Graph api :
`https://graph.facebook.com/{PHOTO_ID}`
The response from that call will contain all the information you need (including a link to the photo on facebook).

Comment: can you give detail about how to use graph api to get the photo url?

Comment: are you using an SDK of some kind? What langugage are you using?

Comment: I use Object-c for iOS device. To upload photo I use [Facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams: andHttpMethod: andDelegate:]

Comment: ok, well i have no knowledge of objective-c - but a graph api call should be very simple. If you can call to `/me/photos` then the call you are looking for is simply `/PHOTO_ID`.

Comment: I don't understand. The photo_id is returned by requestWithGraphPath, then what should I do?

Comment: you posted in a comment above - "me/photos" - make the same calls to only `photo_id`